# Removing columns from a table

Tags: html, css

I'm following a [tutorial](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i3:-tagging) on how to create a Ruby-on-Rails blogging website with comments and tags, and have put my work so far on https://github.com/khpeek/jumpstart-blogger/.

The last part of the tutorial involves allowing authors to create user names and passwords. One of the pages is a default listing of the authors from the "sorcery" gem:

[image]

As you can see, there are blank columns with "Password" and "Password confirmation", which I'd like to remove.

The appearance of this page is governed by `app/views/authors/index.html.erb`, which reads

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Authors</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Password</th>
      <th>Password confirmation</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @authors.each do |author| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= author.username %></td>
        <td><%= author.email %></td>
        <td><%= author.password %></td>
        <td><%= author.password_confirmation %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', author %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_author_path(author) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', author, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Author', new_author_path %>
```

My thought was to comment out the lines

```
  <th>Password</th>
  <th>Password confirmation</th>
```

and

```
    <td><%= author.password %></td>
    <td><%= author.password_confirmation %></td>
```

However, if I do this, some text gets placed outside the main bounding box:

[image]

Is it possible to tell from this limited portion of the code what is going wrong here?

Comment: How did you comment the code, Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you have no style to "tell" your table to fill the full width.

Try adding the following stylesheet:

```
<style>
  table { width: 100%; }
</style>
```

Comment: I added `table {width: 1000%}` in `app/assets/stylesheets/styles.css.css`, but the text outside the box is still there (although the text inside the box is better distributed horizontally). I commented out the lines using "Cntrl+/" in Atom Editor, which yields a line like so: `<!-- <th>Password</th>-->`.

Comment: Can you update your post with the commented file and the generated HTML?